# QT accept udp link instead of local video file

Tags: qt, udp, qmediaplayer, vlc-qt

I am trying accept a udp video stream instead of a local video file. The code below is used to grab video from my local drive and upon running the program the video will load and play on the gui display.

```
QMediaPlayer *mediaplayer = new QMediaPlayer;
mediaplayer ->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/user/video/demo.wmv"));
mediaplayer ->play();
```

Is there any way I can accept a udp video stream and plays it in the QMediaPlayer?

[update]

I am using the vlc-qt library in my project. With reference to [this tutorial](http://derekmolloy.ie/custom-video-streaming-player-using-libvlc-and-qt/)

```
 instance = new VlcInstance(VlcCommon::args(), this);
 player = new VlcMediaPlayer(instance);
 player->setVideoWidget();//accepts a widget
```

However, my program crashes when the vlc instance is created. Please advice.

Comment: Define "UDP video stream". Can you play it with VLC (for example)? What's the URL?

Comment: @hyde I am making use of the library vlc-qt to create a vlc instance. However my code would just crash upon the creation of the vlc instance. I have updated my code as above.

Comment: @hyde the Url is something like this "udp://@:1234"